# WPF - Datagrid ICollectionView binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Below XAML snippet has a simple datagrid binding to a `ICollectionView SysPropViewCollection` which doesn't result in the any data shown in the datagrid - However, if I change the binding to an `ObservableCollection SystemPropertiesList` the datagrid is populated as expected.
Can you help point out if binding constructs/usage is different when using `ICollectionView`? There are no binding failures reported in VS2019 when I build/run the application.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid 
    Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ColumnWidth="Auto"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    RowHeight="20"
    ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName=ConfigEditor, Path=SysPropViewModel.SysPropCollectionView}"
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Environment" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Environment}" 
            MinWidth="100" 
            Width="Auto">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```
 private ObservableCollection<SystemProperties> systemPropertiesList;
public ICollectionView SysPropCollectionView { get; private set; }

public  ObservableCollection<SystemProperties> SystemPropertiesList
{
    get => systemPropertiesList;
    set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref systemPropertiesList, value, () => SystemPropertiesList)) return;
        SysPropCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(systemPropertiesList);
        SysPropCollectionView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the value of the SysPropCollectionView property, but you don't notify it.
I don't know which VM base class you are using, so I can't write for sure.
There should be something like this:

```cs
public  ObservableCollection<SystemProperties> SystemPropertiesList
{
    get => systemPropertiesList;
    set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref systemPropertiesList, value, () => SystemPropertiesList))
            return;
        SysPropCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(systemPropertiesList);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SysPropCollectionView));
    }
}
```

I also advise you to check the overloads of the SetProperty method. In typical implementations, there is usually an overload like this:

```cs
    set
    {
        if (!SetProperty(ref systemPropertiesList, value))
            return;
```

**Supplement.**
To avoid such errors, I would rather use replaced the SysPropCollectionView property type and make a different implementation.
Since creating a property for the DefaultView is pretty pointless.
For all used collections, WPF does this automatically.

```cs
    public CollectionViewSource SysPropCollectionViewSource {get;} = new();
    
    private ObservableCollection<SystemProperties> systemPropertiesList;
    
    public  ObservableCollection<SystemProperties> SystemPropertiesList
    {
        get => systemPropertiesList;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref systemPropertiesList, value))
                SysPropCollectionViewSource.Source = value;
        }
    }
```

In fact, you can drop the SystemPropertiesList property and use the SysPropCollectionViewSource.Source attached property instead. This is a DependencyProperty so no notification is needed to change it.

Comment: @rahul , read the **Supplement**.